# Does MS Word on Apple has any command line interface?

Tags: ms-office, command-line

I wonder if  MS Word on Apple has any command line interface?

I tried the following:

```
$ "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word" --help
```

but no help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Joining @Robuust: What is your plan?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some stuff on Word using the CLI AppleScript is the way to do it.